# Cannot remove event listener in GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

I have an event that I register on a button click:

```
 var paths=[];
 var mapPolylineListener=e.addEventToTarget(map,'click',function(event){
    //keep adding points to the array
    //draw the polyline if there are two points
    //extend the polyline with this point once it has been drawn 
 }

 e.addEventToTargetOnce(map,'rightclick',function(event){
    console.log('Polyline right click event called');
    if(typeof mapPolylineListener!='undefined')
    {
      console.log('stop drawing the map listener');
          //do stuff here like encoding to geometry and making AJAX calls
      paths=[];
      mapPolylineListener=void 0;
    }
```

The events module defines the functions:

```
  addEventToTarget:function(onWhat,eventType,fn)
  {
     gmaps.event.addListener(onWhat,eventType,fn);
  }

  addEventToTargetOnce:function(onWhat,eventType,fn)
  {
    gmaps.event.addListenerOnce(onWhat,eventType,fn);
  }
```

I am using requirejs modules and I used modules to specify functionality:

```
 e=gmaps.event;
 gmaps=window.google.maps;
```

In my console,it displays:

```
  Polyline right click event called
```

and the check always seems to fail

```
 if(typeof mapPolylineListener!='undefined')
```

So,I have tried doing a `!=null` and `if(mapPolylineListener)` check both of which failed.

How can I fix this so that the code within the if block is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how requirejs module works... Because nothing is returned from `addEventToTarget` I would change the following:

```
addEventToTarget:function(onWhat,eventType,fn)
{
    var handle = gmaps.event.addListener(onWhat,eventType,fn);
    return handle;
}
```

and then call `removeListener(mapPolylineListener)` in `e.addEventToTargetOnce(map,'rightclick',function(event){...`